Supabase: User and session is always null in Android (Kotlin) when using Twitter login
So, I'm creating an Android application with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose. I want to integrate it with a Twitter login. I followed this guide. I can log in successfully, and the user is created in the Users table in the supabase server. However, the method always returns null when I try to get the current user supabase.auth.currentUserOrNull(). Any help would be appreciated.
This is how I log in:
Button(onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                try {
                    supabase.auth.signInWith(Twitter)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("TwitterLoginScreen", e.message, e)
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Login with Twitter")
        }

This is the intent filter in my Activity:
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="supabase_host"/>
                <data android:pathPrefix="/auth/v1/callback"/>
            </intent-filter>

And this is my client configuration
object SupabaseClientProvider {
    val supabaseClient = createSupabaseClient(
        supabaseUrl = "URL",
        supabaseKey = "KEY"
    ) {
        install(Postgrest)
        install(Auth)
        install(Storage)
    }
}

